# Saving combobox value to file.

Tags: c#, combobox

I've looked all around and can't find how I could do it.

Forgive me for being ignorant, I've tried a few methods but they never write the value to the text file although it's error free.

http://gyazo.com/8c60124bdf1644460e1b72005c02a187.png

So, I want it to save "here" to a text file.

Thanks.

Jack.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(path, "here");`

Comment: Do Google really return no results when you search stuff like "c# get combobox value" and "c# write file"? Damn, I'll have to find an other search engine

Comment: I've found your first mistake then

Comment: Jack said he worked and looked online to no avail. These other comments aren't constructive... We've all been in a situation where the solution to our program was easy to some but not to us - we should be nice, as other people might find this page useful too.

Welcome to StackOverflow, Jack - I hope you enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things.

1. Get the combo box's selected value
2. Save it

Here's how

```
// ... the rest of your program
string path = "C:\\My Text Files";
string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
File.WriteAllText(path, selectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

File.WriteAllText(path, combobox.SelectedItem.ToString());

or if your combobox is filled with ClassA types:

File.WriteAllText(path, ((ClassA)combobox.SelectedItem).yourMethod());